# Content of Listview gets drawn over UI elements below in Flutter

Tags: mobile, dart, flutter, mobile-development, drawingcontext

Could someone help me with the following issue? I am not sure if this is a bug or intended behaviour. I have the following layout:

```
Column(
    Flexible( ListView[..] )

    Row(
        Flexible(
            TextField(..) <-- input field
        ),
        Container(Icon[]) <-- button

)
```

Scrolling very very quickly makes the content of my ListView getting drawn over the Row in the other container? Could this be a bug in Flutters drawing engine or did I miss to set some boundaries for my ListView?

---

## Normal / expected layout:

[image]

---

## After scrolling very quickly:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is an issue already fixed in `dev` channel.

Execute in command line shell

```
flutter channel dev
flutter doctor
```

Comment: Excellent! Seems my problem got fixed. Thanks for the help (again) :-)